# How to create a DataFrame from existing DataFrame with count of a few columns as a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a new data frame from an existing data frame with the count of existing columns in the data frame.
Let's assume I have following DataFrame

| cus_Type | ID | ID_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| R | 100 | X |
| S | 100 | Y |
| R | 101 | X |
| S | 102 | Y |
| P | 103 | X |
| B | 104 | Y |
| P | 105 | X |
| B | 106 | Y |
| K | 108 | D |

I would like to create a new data Frame from the above with following 'count' of cus_Type ,ID_type like below:

| cus_Type | ID_type | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| R | X | 2 |
| S | Y | 2 |
| P | X | 2 |
| B | Y | 2 |
| K | D | 1 |

I am trying to use pd.groupby(['cus_Type','ID_type']) but not sure how to bring count as  a new column in the existing data frame.

Comment: `df.groupby(['cus_Type','ID_type'])['ID_type'].count()` ?

Answer (score 1):

Some options:

```
df.value_counts(['cus_Type', 'ID_type'], sort=False).reset_index(name='count')
```

Or:

```
df.groupby(['cus_Type', 'ID_type'], sort=False, as_index=False).agg(count=('ID', 'count'))
```

Or:

```
df.groupby(['cus_Type', 'ID_type'], sort=False)['ID'].count().reset_index(name='count')
```

output:

```
  cus_Type ID_type  count
0        R       X      2
1        S       Y      2
2        P       X      2
3        B       Y      2
4        K       D      1
```